# How to enter data in table having columns with same id, class, xpath and css using webdriver?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a table for entering name, email id and relationship but all the columns are having same id, same class, same name, xpath and css. So how can I write code to add data in the columns. 
I meant that all the rows under the column "Name" is having same id, same class, same name, xpath and css. So when I code it, the name is entered in first row for name but it is not getting entered in the second row.
The HTML for the First column for Name field is

```
<input type="text" value="" title="Enter name of the user" name="Name" id="Name" class="required wid220"></pre>
```

The HTML for the second column for Name field is

```
<input type="text" value="" title="Enter name of the user" name="Name" id="Name" class="wid220 validEntry">
```

The HTML for the Third column for Name field is

```
<input type="text" value="" title="Enter name of the user" name="Name" id="Name" class="wid220 validEntry">
```

Comment: Without the html for the table and columns, no can suggest an answer for your query.

Comment: xpath can never be the same. Provide the html. You can get the answer.

Comment: I have 3 text boxes and the xpath, id, class, css are the same. The HTML for one of the box is <input type="text" value="" title="Enter name of the user" name="Name" id="Name" class="required wid220">

Comment: @Dinu, please post the HTML of *all* three text boxes and put them into your question (you can edit your question after it's posted). Posting *all* three will help us see the *true* differences between the textboxes.

Comment: @Arran  I have added the HTML of 3 colmuns

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique on a page.  Bad HTML is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can talk to the developers of this application, then you need to strongly protest that this is a poor standard of application development. Coming to your query, you can use the column xpath to distinguish between different inputs...example:-

```
//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input for first column;  

//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input for second and so on.....
```

tr - represents row, td - represents column

If the table has an id or attribute you can use it like this,

```
//table[@id='value']/tbody/.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void EnterInTable(int rowNumber, string value)
{
    // We don't care about the column as long as you have one text field here
    string query = String.Format("//table[*some-id*]//td[{0}]//input", rowNumber);
    driver.findElement(:xpath, query).sendKeys = value;
}
```